# Capturing Specific Data using Batch Script

Tags: xml, batch-file

Hi so I need help on how I can get specific data from multiple XML files and put it in variable or into one list.

The sample XML is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    </DataPoints>
    <TestResults index="Sensor1">
      <Passed>true</Passed>
    ...
```

My question is: I need to take the value which is located between the `<TestResults index="Sensor1"\>` tags, which is the `<Passed\>true\</Passed\>`.

I tried many things but I didn't manage to do it and I need only the Test result if is Passed or Failed.

So how can I take this value and put it into a variable?

Comment: I can only see the `<Passed>` tag once in your entire file, so what's wrong with using the `find.exe` utility? ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "<Passed>true" 0<"Y:\our\Directory\File.xml" 1>NUL && (Echo Passed) || Echo Failed```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "put this line in bold ( <Passed>true</Passed>) "? Can you edit your question and add the exact expected output?

Comment: Please edit this post to remove the information you believe is sensitive, without invalidating existing answers, then moderators can redact it accordingly.

Comment: Hi. I edited my post and just leave the points that I looked for an answer.

Comment: Thanks, we will redact it as soon as possible

Comment: Is it also possible to remove my long post to my history? Coz my company wants me to do this. They can still see my original post containing sensitive data.

Comment: Redaction will erase the post history too, however it must be approved by two moderators. I already performed the redaction, which is now pending. As soon as another mod comes along and reviews this, the redaction will be effective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is just one `<Passed>true|false</Passed>` line in all files, then the solution is very simple:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.xml) do for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('findstr "Passed" "%%f"') do echo %%f: %%a
```

If there are several `Passed` lines and you want the one that is after `<TestResults index="Sensor1">` one, then use this method:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Process all *.xml files
for %%f in (*.xml) do (

   rem Get the line number of "TestResults index=Sensor1"
   for /F "delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /N /C:"TestResults index=\"Sensor1\"" "%%f"') do (

      rem Show the result from first "Passed" line after "TestResults"
      set "first="
      for /F "delims=:<> tokens=1,4" %%a in ('findstr /N "Passed" "%%f"') do (
         if not defined first  if %%a gtr %%i (
            echo %%f: %%b
            set "first=True"
         )
      )

   )
)
```

Comment: Is it also possible the data that will be capture as true or false using the script above will be in one list that I can review anytime?

Comment: If you execute the Batch file this way: `theBatch.bat > result.txt` the output is stored in `result.txt` file, that you can review anytime

Comment: Hi Aacini, I executed it with your suggested way but the txt result is blank when I open it.

Comment: The `theBatch.bat > result.txt` form store in `result.txt` file _the exact same output_ that `theBatch.bat` file show in the screen. So, show `theBatch.bat` file alone the output you want in the screen?

Comment: This works in combined with your script above. 

@echo off

if exist report.txt erase report.txt

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you...  **`:(`**

Comment: I mean it is working now. :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\xmldata.xml"
SET "index="

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=<> " %%g IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF DEFINED index IF "%%g"=="Passed" SET "passed=%%h"
 IF DEFINED index GOTO done
 IF "%%g"=="TestResults" SET %%h
)

:done
IF DEFINED passed (ECHO FOR %index% - %passed%) ELSE (ECHO NOT found)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

Read the file, tokenising each line using <kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> as delimiters. Select the first 2 tokens to `%%g` and `%%h`.

If the first token is "Testresults", execute `set %%h`. `%%h` will be `index="something"`, so the variable `index` will be set to `"something"`.

Read the next line. If `index` has been set and the first token is `Passed`, then set `passed` to the second token and exit.

If `index` has been set but the first token on the next line is not `Passed`, then exit (presumed error condition)

Report results.